If $A\Rightarrow B$, how does $\bar{A}$ say nothing about B?
I'm reading Probability Theory by E.T. Jaynes and in the first chapter on plausible reasoning, he states

The proposition $A\Rightarrow B$ does not assert that either A or B is
true; it means only that $A\bar{B}$ is false, or, what is the same
thing, ($\bar{A}$ + B) is true ... On the other hand, if A is false,
it says nothing about B: and if B is true, it says nothing about A.

If $A\Rightarrow B$ is the same as $\bar{A} + B$, which means "either A is false or B is true", and A is indeed false, that means ($\bar{A} + B$) is true, right? It doesn't matter whether B is true or false? Is this what the author means by the emphasized statement?

Yes, see Truth table for conditional

You should consider a simple example. Say, condition $A$ for an integer $n>2$ is that it is even, and condition $B$ is that it is not prime. Then $A\Rightarrow B$. If $A$ is false, then what about $B$? Or if $B$ is true, then what about $A$?

@DietrichBurde yes thank you I think I see now. So if $A$ is false, $n$ is odd; I see how that says nothing about the truth value of $B$ (whether $n$ is prime). In other words when $A$ is false, $A \Rightarrow B$ is true no matter what. I'm confused given your conditions though, since $n$ being odd does not imply that $n$ is not prime -- does that say something about our choice of conditions?

I'm confused given your conditions though, since $n$ being odd does not imply that $n$ is not prime - so this just says that $\overline{A}$ does not imply $B$, as you wanted to know in your title. So being odd says nothing about being not prime, or being prime.

If $A$ is odd, that says nothing about $B$ not being prime.  And $B$ being not prime says nothing about $A$ being even.  Maybe a less binary and more actively positively defined condition (rather than "not prime") could be $A$= "$w$ is an integer" and $B$= "$w$ is rational".  $A \implies B$ is the same as $A\overline B$= "$w$ is an irrational integer" is false and as $\overline A+B=$"either $w$ is rational or it isn't and integer" is true.  If $w$ is not an integer, that says nothing about whether it is rational.  And if $w$ is irrational that says nothing about whether it is an integer.

It should be "if $w$ is rational that says nothing about whether it is an integer".

"If it's raining, the ground is wet" is a true statement.  But if it's not raining, that doesn't tell you anything about whether the ground is wet.

So is the general rule that an implication only has a meaningful truth value when both propositions are true or the consequent is false?

$A = $ "it is raining. $B = $ "the ground is wet". $A \Rightarrow B$ is true; when $A$ is false (i.e. "it is not raining"), $A \Rightarrow B$ is still true but it doesn't tell us anything helpful. Is that right?

It might be useful to notice that the combination "A $\implies$ B" and "not A" doesn't contain any more information then just "not A" (because "A $\implies$ B" is a  consequence of "not A"), So it is to be expected that the combination tells you nothing about B; after all, "not A" doesn't say anything about B.

Because "if A , then B" only applies if $A$ is true. Otherwise nothing can be concluded , in particular nothing about $B$.

"Update the question so it focuses on one problem only." I see only a single issue here--whether the OP's interpretation of a sentence in  a textbook is correct.  I tried to explain why it is correct using a real-world example. Voting to reopen.


If $A\Rightarrow B$ is the same as $\bar{A} + B$, which means "either
A is false or B is true", and A is indeed false, that means ($\bar{A}+ B$) is true, right? It doesn't matter whether B is true or false? Is this what the author means by the emphasized statement?

Yes. I will try to explain why with another "rainy-day" example, using a more standard notation:

It is raining ($R$) implies it is cloudy ($C$). (Present tense)
$R\implies C$

In classical logic, this does not mean that rain causes cloudiness. Or that it is always cloudy when it is raining (e.g. so-called "sunshowers"). It rules out only the possibility that it is currently raining and not cloudy:

$\neg (R \land \neg C)$

Or equivalently, as in your example:

$\neg R \lor C$

This is entirely consistent with the truth table:

Note the following:

Where both '$R$' and '$R\implies C$' are true (line 1 only), we have '$C$' being true. (The detachment or modus ponens rule)
Where '$R$' is false (lines 3 and 4), we have '$R\implies C$' being true
regardless of the truth value of '$C$'
Where '$C$' is true (lines 1 and 3), we have '$R\implies C$' being true
regardless of the truth value of '$R$'


Text version of truth table
R C R=>C
T T T
T F F
F T T
F F T

This is a really helpful explanation, thank you. So a false proposition implies all propositions in the sense that, if $R$ is false, $R \Rightarrow C$ is true on the grounds that the proposition "it is not raining" encompasses the essentially infinite alternative ways it could be come cloudy? In other words, how do we interpret the statement "It is raining ($R$) implies it is cloudy ($C$)" when it is not in fact raining?

Indeed, for example take  $6|x \Rightarrow 2|x $. If $6|x $ then $2|x$, so $(\overline{6|x}+2|x)$ is true (as $2|x$). If $6\not|x$, then $(\overline{6|x}+2|x)$ is correct, no matter if $2|x$ or $2\not|x$ (as $\overline{6|x}$ is true).
